Cookies in Next.js 14 Route Handler Called from SSR Page not working
I'm working on a Next.js 14 project using the app router and encountering issues with accessing HTTP-only cookies from a route handler that fetches data from an external API. This route handler is called by an SSR page, and I want to create a modular approach to handle these API calls, particularly for a specific endpoint, with the added requirement of caching the route handler. However, I'm unable to retrieve the auth_token cookie within the route handler when it's invoked from an SSR page, despite the cookie being correctly set and accessible in other scenarios.
Setup:

SSR Page: I’m calling a route handler using fetch() within an SSR page.

Route Handler: The route handler attempts to access the cookie using cookies() from next/headers, but it fails to retrieve the cookie when called from the SSR page. This route handler makes a call to an external web service API, passing the authentication token stored in the HTTP-only cookie.


Issue:
The cookie retrieval works perfectly when I call the web service directly from the SSR page. However, I want to use a more modular approach because I will be calling this endpoint in subsequent pages, and I would like to cache the route handler for performance optimization.
Things I’ve Tried:

Cookie Presence: I've confirmed that the cookie exists by inspecting it through the browser's dev tools. The cookie is set as HTTP-only, secure, and SameSite is set to strict.

Direct Browser Access: Calling the route handler directly via the browser works fine, and the cookie is retrieved without issues. However, when accessed via SSR, the cookie is null.

GitHub Discussion: I referred to this GitHub discussion, which states:
“cookies().getAll() does not work in Route Handler, IF AND ONLY you make request from the SERVER COMPONENT. If you make request to route Handler from CLIENT COMPONENT, you will definitely get cookies by cookies().getAll() .”
However, I couldn't find this information in the official Next.js documentation.


Important:

What the Route Handler Does: The route handler fetches data from an external web service API. It first tries to retrieve the auth_token cookie, which is then used as a Bearer token in the API request header.
How it Works When Calling the Web Service Directly: When I make the API call directly from the SSR page, I can successfully retrieve the auth_token cookie and pass it to the web service, which works as expected. However, this approach reduces modularity because I need to call this web service in subsequent pages.

Code Examples:
SSR Page:

import React from 'react'

export default async function Page() {
  
  const response = await fetch(`/api/events`)
  const data = await response.json()
  return <div>{data.map(event => <div key={event.id}>{event.name}</div>)}</div>
}

Route Handler (api/events):
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

export async function GET(request) {
  const cookieStore = cookies()
  const authToken = cookieStore.get('auth_token')?.value
  if (!authToken) {
    return NextResponse.json({ status: 401, error: 'Unauthorized' })
  }

  // Make API call with the auth token and return the response
  const apiUrl = `${process.env.MY_API_URL}/api/Events`
  const apiResponse = await fetch(apiUrl, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${authToken}`
    }
  })

  const data = await apiResponse.json()
  return NextResponse.json(data)
}

Questions:

Is there something specific about SSR in Next.js 14 that might be causing this issue with accessing HTTP-only cookies from a route handler?
Should I continue with the direct web service call in the SSR page despite the reduced modularity, or is there a better approach?
Can anyone confirm the information from the GitHub thread regarding cookies in route handlers when called from SSR pages? If so, do you have any suggestions on creating a modular approach to handle this situation while ensuring that the route handler can be cached?

